# cURL returns partial page dom

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, php-curl

I have a script that scrapes other sites.
One of the sites I scrape suddenly started returning a partial HTML response. Meaning, the entire DOM is not returned.

Here is my code:

```
$url = "https://example.com";
$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A');
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Expect:'));
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');


    $response['str'] = curl_exec($curl);
    var_dump($response);    
    $response['header'] = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($curl);
```

So, when I var_dump the $response I get a partial HTML response (It doesn't seem like this specific URL loads content with AJAX. When going to this URL with a browser it loads all together in the source)

I can't seem to find an answer that fixes this issue. I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you

Comment: Just a tip, don't use `var_dump` as it might be limiting the amount of data printed, try using `echo` or `print_r` instead

Comment: This was just for the purpose of this question. but thank you